# Third party scripts detection with ad-blockers

Tags: adblock

Conceptually how do ad-blockers detect third party scripts? Is it a reverse firewall, or do they read all of the incoming code when a page is requested? or something else?

Answer (score -1):

In the case of Adblock Plus it checks whether the requesting host has the same base domain as the requested host by comparing the two URLs that the browser provide when a new request is being made.

Source:

- [Adblock Plus for Firefox](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockplus/blob/e362a4f14e3206f03cc461854327326a5f26f10d/lib/contentPolicy.js#L768)
- [Adblock Plus for Chrome/Opera/Safari](https://github.com/adblockplus/adblockpluschrome/blob/bf447164cdf823c085c42705c8cc767e831cf272/lib/url.js#L155)

Comment: **Maybe in the past**, and until recently (1/2 year ago) in Chrome. **Now Days** (and for Firefox, for the past 8 years) - **AdBlock hooks the network API of the browser**, killing connections very early in the page life-cycle (if any!). Some hiding rules naturally are not requiring such methods, but as for 3'rd party resources, that's the way now days.. I could reference this the adblock GIT||SVN, but [..give a man a fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime) ;)